# Why doesn't background shorthand work for ids?

Tags: css

I have no idea why this doesn't work for ids. If I change #slide1 to body, it works. What's happening here? Thanks.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q43Sm/1/

```
<div class="foo">
    <div id="slide1"></div>
    <div id="slide2"></div>
    <div id="slide3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.foo { display: inline-block; }

#slide1 { background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1') no-repeat top; }
#slide2 { background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2') no-repeat top; }
#slide3 { background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3') no-repeat top; }
```

Comment: your divs have zero height, so they won't be rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding some CSS to your divs?

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q43Sm/3/)**

```
 .foo {
    display: inline-block;
}
#slide1 {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1') no-repeat top;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
#slide2 {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2') no-repeat top;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
#slide3 {
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3') no-repeat top;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is right but comment if you are not sure, rather than answering like this

Answer (score 2):

Body is a large area. Well, not really. Body has no content, so a background wouldn't show. But `html` (which auto-inflates to the viewport height) inherits (backward) the background. Just some random div with no hight wouldn't have this effect.

You can give the random div a height by making it and it's parents height `100%`. For this case *(If you want images to be 100% `height` and `width` of the viewport)*,

```
html, body, .foo, .foo * { height: 100% }
```

Since your `div.foo` is `inline-block`, you also need to se it to `width: 100%`.

Comment: Nope, nothing to do with `height: 100%;`, the elements are wrapped inside an `inline-block` element, assigning `height` to the `div` will work, you solution is applicable if OP wanted the images to be of height 100% of the viewport

Comment: @MR.Alien Does inline-block matter? It's height can still be set. Isn't `height: 100%` exactly what OP wanted?

Comment: nah :) I don't see he states 100% height anywhere :) he actually thinks that background shorthand fails..

Comment: He says it fails, expecting it to behave like putting it on `body`, i.e 100%.

Comment: ummmm no, but keep your answer as its different from others, this might help if he is looking for full screen backgrounds...

Comment: ummmm no what? Can you explain why you think my answer is wrong?

Comment: I am not saying its wrong, you got the question in a wrong way, read the question again, he thinks background property fails but the fact is that it works, **BUT** he has wrapped all the divs inside an inline-block parent hence width is 0, also, div has nothing in there so height will be 0, so we need to assign height and width to the child divs, so no need of 100% heights here, also if you give 100% height this wont work as they are inside inline-block so width will be 0.. hope you got it now

Comment: King had a similar view, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23967707/why-doesnt-background-shorthand-work-for-ids/23967738?noredirect=1#comment36926559_23967731)

Comment: @Mr.Alien **Inline-block does not affect the height!**

Comment: *sigh* I cannot explain you more :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54832/discussion-between-mr-alien-and-bjb568).

Answer (score 1):

Because they don't have width and height. Take a look at the modified fiddle:

```
.foo { display: inline-block; }

#slide1 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1') no-repeat top; }
#slide2 { background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2') no-repeat top; }
#slide3 { background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3') no-repeat top; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q43Sm/2/

Comment: in fact we just need specify the `height` to see it work, the `width` of a div will fill the whole space (100%) by default.

Comment: @KingKing nope, the divs are wrapped inside `inline-block` so again, no `width` :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien ah yes, missed the style `.foo`

Answer (score 0):

```
     .foo { 
             display: block;height:200px;width:100px;border:1px solid red;
      }
```